# .Net How Select a Particular Row In dataGridView when User Right Clicks

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a datagridview control that i want to perform some operations on when the user right clicks on a particular row but the datagridview can only select the row when the row is firstly left clicked before right clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to the CellMouseDown event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.RowIndex >=0)
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```